# DynamoDB - UpdateItem where X <= Y

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDb table defined with a composite key of

```
        $response = $this->dynamoDb->createTable([
            ...
            'KeySchema' => [
                [
                    'AttributeName' => 'product_code',
                    'KeyType' => 'HASH' 
                ],
                [
                    'AttributeName' => 'token',
                    'KeyType' => 'RANGE' 
                ]
            ]
            ...
        ]);
```

I want to be able to update all records where "product_code" = "X" and "created_at" <= "Y". I assume it must be possible but I am a bit stumped. The updateItem method requires the full key but I want a conditional update without specifying a key. My latest stub reads as

```
        $response = $this->dynamoDb->updateItem([
            'TableName' =>  'products',
            'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [
                ':val1'    =>  ['N' => (string)$this->input['product_code']]
                ':val2'    =>  ['N' => (string)$this->product['created_at']['N']],
                ':val3'    =>  ['N' => (string)strtotime("now")],

            ],
            'ConditionExpression'   =>  'product_code = :val1 AND processed_at <= :val2',
            'UpdateExpression'      =>  'set processed_at = :val3'
        ]);
```

But the generated error message reads as follows:

```
[Key] is missing and is a required parameter
```

Which command should I be using? Any help building my query is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from AWS DynamoDB API reference for UpdateItem:

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.

In your code (the update item part) you provide only hash key (`product_code`). You have to provide the range key (`token`) as well in your `ConditionExpression` property, because you defined a composite key.

**EDIT:**

(regarding the comment)

The following describes the parameters for UpdateItem:

> **Request Parameters**
>
> ...
>
> **Key**
>
> The primary key of the item to be updated. Each element consists of an
>   attribute name and a value for that attribute.
>
> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For
>   example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value
>   for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide
>   values for both the partition key and the sort key.
>
> Type: String to AttributeValue object map
>
> Required: Yes
>
> ...

As you can see, the primary key is required for an UpdateItem operation.
So you cannot use a secondary index to point UpdateItem to a collection of items to update.

However, you can [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) the table by a secondary index, and collect the primary keys of the resulted items, say in an array `keysToUpdate`.
Then you can update the desired items, whose keys are in `keyToUpdate`.

Comment: after your edit my answer would change just a bit. Notice that you must provide the range key, in this case - `token` (and formerly `created_at`) in the `ConditionExpression` property

Comment: The issue is I do not want to use the token, else I will only retrieve one record(?) because it creates a unique composite key. I need to update all records based on product_code and the value of procesed_at. I have created a secondary index that uses product_code and processed_at. But not sure if I am on the right lines.